# Prob. 2, Chap. 6, in Baby Rudin: If $f\geq 0$ and continuous on $[a,b]$ with $\int_a^bf(x)\ \mathrm{d}x=0$, then $f=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, proof-verification, definite-integrals

Here is Prob. 2, Chap. 6, in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Suppose $f \geq 0$, $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, and $\int_a^b f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x = 0$. Prove that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.

My Attempt:

> Let $c$ and $d$ be any points in $[a, b]$ such that $c \leq d$. As $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ and as $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, so $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in [c, d]$ and $f$ is continuous on $[c, d]$; therefore $f \in \mathscr{R}$ on $[c, d]$ and 
>   $$ \int_c^d f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x \geq \int_c^d \hat{0}(x) \ \mathrm{d} x = 0$$
>   by Theorem 6.12 (b) in Baby Rudin, where $\hat{0}$ denotes the *zero function* on $[c, d]$. That is, 
>   $$ \int_c^d f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x \geq 0 \tag{0}$$
>   for any points $c$ and $d$ such that $a \leq c \leq d \leq b$.
>
> Suppose that there is a point $p \in [a, b]$ such that $f(p) >  0$. Then, as $f$ is continuous at $p$, so, for any real number $\varepsilon$ such that 
>   $$ 0 < \varepsilon < \frac{  f(p) }{2}, $$
>   we can find a real number $\delta > 0$ such that 
>   $$ \lvert f(x) - f(p) \rvert < \varepsilon < \frac{ f(p) }{2} $$
>   for all $x \in [a, b]$ for which 
>   $ \lvert x-p \rvert < \delta$.
>
> Therefore, we can conclude that
>   $$ \frac{ f(p) }{2} < f(x) < \frac{3 f(p) }{2} \tag{1} $$
>   for all $x \in I$, where 
>   $$I \colon= [a, b] \cap \left[ p- \frac{\delta}{2}, p+ \frac{\delta}{2} \right]. $$ 
>   Let's put $I \colon= [u, v]$. Then we see that 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_a^b f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x &= \int_a^u f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x + \int_u^v f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x + \int_v^b f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x \\
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ by an extension of Theorem 6.12 (c) in Baby Rudin ] } \\
> &\geq \int_u^v f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x \qquad \mbox{ [ by (0) above ] } \\ 
> &\geq \int_u^v \frac{f(p)}{2}  \ \mathrm{d} x  \qquad \mbox{ [ using (1) and Theorem 6.12 (b) in Baby Rudin ] } \\
> &= \frac{f(p)}{2} (v-u) \\
> &> 0, \qquad \mbox{ [ by (2) and our choice of $u$ and $v$ above ] } 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   which contradicts our hypothesis that $\int_a^b f(x) \ \mathrm{d} x = 0$.

Is this proof sound enough in terms of its logic and rigor? If so, then is it also lucid enough in its presentation?

Comment: Your proof seems great. I would just suggest to avoid the introduction of $\epsilon$ which is not necessary.

Comment: This should be the proof of the contrapositive, not a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @egreg The author of this proof is proceeding by contradiction; namely assuming that there is a point $p$ where $f(p)>0$, and then deducing a contradiction of what we assumed about the integral of $f$.

Comment: @AOrtiz That's exactly what I objected to: the proof is *unnecessarily* by contradiction. If $f$ takes on a positive value, the integral is positive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proof is fine. A little wordy and perhaps using more notation than you need, but it's correct.

I would have phrased it thusly:

*Proof.* Suppose $c\in [a,b]$ is such that $f(c)>0$. By continuity of $f$, there is a closed interval $[r,s]$ of $c$ where $f>f(c)/2>0$. By monotonicity of the integral,
$$
\int_a^bf \ge \int_r^sf\ge \int_r^sf(c)/2>0,
$$
which is a contradiction by what we assumed about $\int_a^b f$. $\qquad\square$